# Why does aws-okta fails sudo apt-get update?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

When I try to run `apt-get update` I get a weird failure.

```
$sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:2 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Release
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:6 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:8 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Ign:11 https://packagecloud.io/segment/aws-okta/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:12 https://packagecloud.io/segment/aws-okta/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.215.161.51 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/segment/aws-okta/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The sources.list files seem ok:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/segment_aws-okta.list
# this file was generated by packagecloud.io for
# the repository at https://packagecloud.io/segment/aws-okta

deb https://packagecloud.io/segment/aws-okta/ubuntu/ focal main
deb-src https://packagecloud.io/segment/aws-okta/ubuntu/ focal main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aws-okta package doesn't exist for Ubuntu Focal, as can be seen from the [list here](https://packagecloud.io/app/segment/aws-okta/search). Because of that, apt complains it can't find the package and you cannot install it.

Furthermore, per their [issue](https://github.com/segmentio/aws-okta/issues/278), development for aws-okta has been indefinitely halted since January and its probably better to look at other options available